# Best way to copy data to a new sheet and reorganize it (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a VBA program which copies and organizes data from one master sheet into numerous other sheets. One of the recipient sheets unifies all the data from the master sheet which holds the same id number into a single row. For this operation, I am looping through the master sheet for each id number, copying each row which holds the current id number into a new sheet purely used for calculations and organizing, and rearranging the data in this sheet into the new row. The resultant row is copied into the recipient sheet. This process of organizing data for every id number takes a long time to process, especially given the very large size of this sheet and the processing time of the other recipient sheets. I'm wondering if there is a better way to organize and copy data without using an intermediate calculation sheet.

The below code is the main sub, which calls another sub OrganizeAndCopyToPal, which organizes the data in the calculation sheet and copies the result into the recipient sheet.

```
Sub PalletAssemblyLog()

    Dim allidNum As Range
    Dim curridNum As Range
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim idNum
    Dim I As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim machineLoc As String
    
    Dim calc As Worksheet
    Dim full As Worksheet
    Dim pal As Worksheet
    Set calc = Sheet3
    Set full = Sheet4
    Set pal = Sheet1
    
    For I = 2 To rowCount
        For j = 2 To rowCount
            If full.Cells(j, 17).Value = idNum Then
                If allidNum Is Nothing Then
                    Set allidNum = full.Cells(j, 17)
                Else
                    Set allidNum = Union(allidNum, full.Cells(j, 17))
                End If
            End If
        Next j
            
        Set curridNum = allidNum.EntireRow
        
        calc.Activate
        calc.Cells.Clear
        
        full.Activate
        curridNum.Copy calc.Range("A1")
        
        OrganizeAndCopyToPal curridNum
    Next I
End Sub
```

The below sub organizes and copies the data for each id number. The final sub to copy the data isn't related to the matter of simplifying this task so I'm not including it.

```
Sub OrganizeAndCopyToPal(curridNum)
    
    Dim calc As Worksheet
    Dim pal As Worksheet
    Set calc = Sheet3
    Set pal = Sheet1
    
    calc.Activate
    
    Dim rowCount As Long
    rowCount = calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim palRow As Long
    palRow = rowCount + 2
    Dim partRow As Long
    partRow = palRow + 2
    
    Dim currPartCount As Range
    
    Dim assembly As String
    Dim id As String
    Dim location As String
    Dim machType As String
    Dim machLoc As String
    Dim currPart As String
    Dim link As String
    Dim tot As Long
    tot = 0
    
    With calc
        .Cells(1, 1).Copy .Cells(palRow, 2)
        assembly = .Cells(1, 1).Value
        
        .Cells(1, 2).Copy .Cells(palRow, 5)
        
        id = .Cells(1, 17).Value
        
        asArray = SplitMultiDelims(id, "|-")
        'MsgBox asArray(0) & " " & asArray(1) & " " & asArray(2)
        machArray = Split(.Cells(1, 8), "-")
        machType = machArray(0)
        .Cells(palRow, 3) = machType
        
        machLoc = .Cells(1, 8).Value
        .Cells(palRow, 4) = machLoc
        
        .Cells(1, 17).Copy .Cells(palRow, 10)

        location = Cells(1, 9)
        .Cells(palRow, 1) = location
        
        For I = 1 To rowCount
            partArray = Split(.Cells(I, 16).Value, ",")
            For j = 0 To UBound(partArray)
                partArray2 = Split(partArray(0), "-")
                partPrefix = partArray2(0)
                If j = 0 Then
                    currPart = partArray(j)
                Else
                    currPart = partPrefix & "-" & CStr(partArray(j))
                End If
                tf = 1
                For k = 0 To tot
                    If Cells(partRow + k, 1).Value = currPart Then
                        tf = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
                If tf = 1 Then
                    .Cells(partRow + tot, 1).Value = currPart
                    tot = tot + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next I
        
        For I = 1 To tot
            Cells(palRow, 10 + I).Value = Cells(partRow + I - 1, 1)
        Next I
        
    End With
    
    CopyToPal curridNum, palRow
    
End Sub
```

Thank you for any tips or help that you can offer.

Comment: If there is no issue with the code you might better want to post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com • Here this would probably generate opinion based answers (which are off-topic).

Comment: In your first block of code you don't assign a value to `idNum`.  Is this your actual code?

Comment: Thanks Pᴇʜ, I didn't know that was a separate forum, I'll repost this there. Tim, This is not my actual code, I removed extraneous portions, but good catch.

Comment: What is a "long time" roughly? How many rows of data approximately, and what is the granularity of the "id" column? (eg. one or two rows per id, one or two hundred, thousand, etc?)  Would help to have some idea of the scale of your problem.

Comment: I'm still developing the full program so I'm not working with the full scale of data. There will always be less than 10 rows per id, and frequently there will be only one row per id. Total rows will probably be around 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting into more exotic solutions - the easiest thing you can do is set

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Before getting stuck into much code.
Then when you need to do an update before copying any data that may change due to formulae calcs, run

```
Application.Calculate
```

and eventually at the end reset it to

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

You can disable screen updates too, but the above will be the big (easy) one. After that we're into copying to arrays and working in them then pasting back.